# Databind in WPF

Tags: wpf

"EDIT"

> What I want to achieve is something like -
>
> MainWindow.xaml contains a Button, a ComboBox and a ContentControl.
>   UserControl-A and UserControl-C both contains a ContentControl.
>   UserControl-B and UserControl-D both contains a TextBlock.
>
> UserControl-B will be Content of ContentControl Contained in
>   UserControl-A. UserControl-D will be Content of ContentControl
>   Contained in UserControl-C.
>
> UserControl-A Or UserControl-C will be Content of ContentControl
>   Contained in MainWindow.xaml on click of the Button.
>
> On change in SelectedValue of Combobox Update TextBlock of
>   UserControl-B Or UserControl-D.

"EDIT"

In addition to MainWindow.xaml, App.xaml and App.config I have MainContent1.xaml, MainContent2.xaml, ComboItems.cs and two subfolder Sub1 and Sub2, each of them contains a single file named S1.xaml, in my project.

All of my code is written in **ComboItems.cs** as -

```
namespace MultiBinding
{ 
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComboItems
{
    public ComboItems()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>(3);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            Items.Add(new Item { Id = i, Name = "Name " + i });           
    }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ButtonContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    private string _content;

    public ButtonContent()
    {
        _content = "First";
        MyCommand = new Command(Do, CanDo);
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { _content = value; OnChange("Content"); }
    }

    private bool CanDo(object parameter) => true;       
    private void Do(object parameter) => Content = Content == "First" ? "Second" : "First";
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnChange(string name) => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> Do;
    private Func<object, bool> CanDo;
    public Command(Action<object> Do, Func<object, bool> CanDo)
    {
        this.Do = Do;
        this.CanDo = CanDo;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => Do(parameter);
}

public class SomeText
{
    public static string Text1 { get; set; }
    public static string Text2 { get; set; }
}


public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (values[1].ToString())
        {
            case "1": SomeText.Text1 = SomeText.Text2 = "Selected Item is 1"; break;
            case "2": SomeText.Text1 = SomeText.Text2 = "Selected Item is 2"; break;
            case "3": SomeText.Text1 = SomeText.Text2 = "Selected Item is 3"; break;
        }

        if (values[0].ToString() == "First") return new MainContent1();
        else return new MainContent2();     
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

**Content of MainWindow.xaml** is -

```
<Window x:Class="MultiBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiBinding">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ComboItems x:Key="cboItems" />
    <local:Item x:Key="Item" />
    <local:Converter x:Key="convert" />
    <local:ButtonContent x:Key="content"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo" 
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Item}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Source={StaticResource cboItems}}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id}"/>

    <Button x:Name="butt" Grid.Column="1"
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource content}}"
            Content="{Binding Path=Content}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource convert}">
                <Binding ElementName="butt" Path="Content"/>
                <Binding ElementName="combo" Path="SelectedValue"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

**Content of MainContent1.xaml** is -

```
<UserControl x:Class="MultiBinding.MainContent1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sub="clr-namespace:MultiBinding.Sub1">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sub:S1 x:Key="s1"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="On Main ContentControl No. 1"/>
    <ContentControl 
        Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource s1}}" 
        Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

MainContent2.xaml contains exact same code as above except

```
xmlns:sub="clr-namespace:MultiBinding.Sub2"
```

**Content of S1.xaml** under folder Sub1 is -

```
<UserControl x:Class="MultiBinding.Sub1.S1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MultiBinding">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <main:SomeText x:Key="MyText"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="Bisque">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1, Source={StaticResource MyText}}"  />
</Grid>
```

S1.xaml under folder Sub2 is similar to that of Sub1 folder except

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text2, Source={StaticResource MyText}}" />
```

Everything works as expected in this way.

Is there any problem using static keyword infront of Text1 and Text2 properties  of SomeText Class in ComboItems.cs?

How can I achieve same functionality without using static properties of SomeText class?

Comment: That is a lot of code to wade through to understand what you are trying to do. You would probably get better help if you write the question in the top and invested some time in reducing the amount of source code. HTH

Comment: Long question, short answer - use MVVM pattern. You can link different controls with a common data model

Comment: @benPearce Am i right following MVVM pattern in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed "ComboItems and Converter" classes from ComboItems.cs, renamed "ButtonContent" class as "MyCode" and implemented it as follows -

```
public class MyCode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Fields
    private Sub1.S1 _s1;
    private Sub2.S1 _s2;
    private MainContent1 _m1;
    private MainContent2 _m2;
    private object _mainContent;
    private object _subContent;
    private int _selectedIndex;

    //Properties
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public object MainContent
    {
        get { return _mainContent; }
        set { _mainContent = value; OnChange("MainContent"); }
    }
    public object SubContent
    {
        get { return _subContent; }
        set { _subContent = value; OnChange("SubContent"); }
    }

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            //Action on selection change
            switch (_selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: Text = "Selected Item is 1"; break;
                case 1: Text = "Selected Item is 2"; break;
                case 2: Text = "Selected Item is 3"; break;
            }
            OnChange("Text");
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public MyCode()
    {
        Content = "First";
        MyCommand = new Command(Do, CanDo);
        _m1 = new MainContent1();
        _m2 = new MainContent2();
        _s1 = new Sub1.S1();
        _s2 = new Sub2.S1();
        MainContent = _m1;
        SubContent = _s1;
        Items = new List<Item>(3);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            Items.Add(new Item { Id = i, Name = "Name " + i });
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    //Action on Button Click                  
    private void Do(object parameter)
    {
        if(Content == "First")
        {
            MainContent = _m2;
            SubContent = _s2;
            Content = "Second";
        }
        else
        {
            MainContent = _m1;
            SubContent = _s1;
            Content = "First";               
        }
        OnChange("Content");
    }

    private bool CanDo(object parameter) => true;
    //Inotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnChange(string name) => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Changed MainWindow.xaml to -

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyCode x:Key="Code"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Code}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions...>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions...>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
    <Button x:Name="butt" Grid.Column="1"              
            Content="{Binding Path=Content}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Content="{Binding Path=MainContent}"/>
</Grid>
```

Both of MainContent1.xaml and MainContent2.xaml now contains -

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SubContent}"/>
```

And S1.xaml under folder Sub1 and Sub2 contains -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
```

Done!